# Weekending date return issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm adding in a weekending date into a column based on a specified date. The weekending date should be the following Sunday unless the date is a Sunday in which case it should use that date.

```
Declare @DateValue DateTime = '6/12/2016' --A Sunday

select DATEADD (dd, -1 * DatePart (DW, @DateValue) + 8, @DateValue)
```

This query returns 2016-06-19 which is the following Sunday and I want to return 2016-06-12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
select DATEADD (dd, iif(DatePart (DW, @DateValue)=1,0,-1 * DatePart (DW, @DateValue) + 8), @DateValue)
```

If you don't have SQL 2012+ as suggested by bjones

```
select DATEADD (dd, case when DatePart (DW, @DateValue)=1 then 0 else -1 * DatePart (DW, @DateValue) + 8 end, @DateValue)
```

Comment: As long as it's >= SQL Server 2012

Comment: Agreed, then a simple case statement

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thank you, I am pre 2012.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend that you create a Calendar table. While John Cappelletti's will work, you'll find that joining to dbo.Calendar will be easier to use and offer better performance.

Why You Simply Must Have a Date Table [Video]: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/simply-must-date-table-video/

Comment: Do you have any links to examples of this approach?

Comment: Added the video that taught me how to use them.

Comment: Seems like overkill for the OP's original stated usage, but if there's other business logic revolving around dates (and from personal experience, there usually is), this actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: At this point I just add one by default. I can't think of any occasion where I haven't needed one eventually.